# How can I access LWC utility functions in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, javascript

We have a custom LWC that contains various utilities we use across our LWC files. I'd like to access these utility functions within a Visualforce page. I know Visualforce can import external scripts that are at URLs or static resources. We're already using this feature to access an open source JS library:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jszip}" />
```

Within other LWC files, we're able to access our own LWC utility features with

```
import { utilityFunc } from 'c/utils';
```

Is there a way I can similarly access these utility functions using the `includeScript` syntax in Visualforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWCs are compiled and bundled. As such, there's no way to documented and reliable way to directly access the contents as you would with a static resource. You could conceptually try to use Lightning Out to embed a utility LWC directly into Visualforce, although I haven't tried that. The more reliable method would be to move the functions to a static resource and use loadScript to access them in LWC. This might require a significant amount of refactoring, though.